# Snippet console.log() return different value than browser console

Tags: bug, stack-snippets, stack-snippets-console

Not sure why the `console.log()` in my snippet return different value of the browser developer console :

[image]

You could see that it return an empty array `[]` instead of filled one like console below.

The snippet belong to the **[Following Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38128797/adding-input-forms-and-removing-them-again-get-all-ids/38128967#38128967)**.

Comment: I would guess it's because your console is also showing the non-numeric properties, but the SO console is skipping them and just showing numeric properties from the array.

Comment: What should be done to reproduce that?

Comment: @nicael Fill the fields and hit the "print" span.

Comment: You shouldn't be using an array. The snippet console is just behaving in a sane way, like Firefox console. Blame Chrome console for being weird.

Comment: _You shouldn't be using an array_ Why @Oriol ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Because the properties of arrays are supposed to be array indices. You should use a normal object instead.